# What does "CTRL + SHIFT + H" do in compiz?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiz

I was trying to open Firefox's browser history with the shortcut key <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> but instead of that I get this sort of diagram over my current window:

[image]

The most awkward part is that if I close this window, Compiz appears to crash.

So, what is the purpose of this "Diagram" and how can I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is part of the **Freely Transformable Windows** plugin:

[image: FTW]

By using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+MouseLeft, you can do some, er, *very interesting* things:

[image: woo linux!]

That overlay is meant to help guide you when manipulating and transforming windows using the above method. Basically, it just gives you a bunch of axes to use so that you can align/work with things more precisely. Regrettably, like with most Compiz plugins, it's sort of fallen out of support and is *kinda* buggy.

[image: how it looks like being used live]

If you don't want this feature, just launch the CompizConfig Settings Manager and disable that plugin. If you don't have CCSM, install it with `apt`:

```
sudo apt install compizconfig-settings-manager
```